# Port forwarding issue

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a RPi with Raspian OS.

On the RPi there is an app called lab_app, running on port 80.

I have installed Nginx.
I have configured Nginx via file `/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_nginx.conf` and symbolically linked to the location of ngnix configurations

```
ln -s /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

the content of `/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_nginx.conf` is

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    
    location /static {
        root /var/www/lab_app/;
    }
    
    location / { try_files $uri @labapp; }
    location @labapp {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.sock;        
    }   
}
```

The RPi and my PC are both linked to the same wifi.
From my pc I can ping the RPi, access it via ssh, and also access via browser the app, by inserting the LAN RPi ip address.

I have exposed the RPi port 80 through my modem UI by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tIUts0fyFk), 
The UI shows in section `NAT forwarding` :

service type: HTTP
external port: 80
internal ip: 192.168.1.106
internal port: 80
protocol: TCP

In my modem UI, on section `network > internet`, I can see my modem ip address.

From my PC, as insert in the browser url bar the modem ip address, it shows the app.

But as I do it from a device not connected to my wifi (e.g. my mobile phone connected with a SIM), I cannot access the app, and I get error message

> impossible to reach teh website. ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

What am I doing wrong?

In nginx log `/var/log/nginx/error.log` there is just this message

```
2024/02/22 21:44:05 [error] 625#625: *1061 connect() to unix:/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 100.72.91.150, server: localhost, request: "GET /lab_temp HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.sock:", host: "100.72.91.150", referrer: "http://100.72.91.150/lab_temp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone operator of the wifi network provided by my modem does not allow port forwarding, that is why the `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` error was raised.

they say "the network is filtered and NATted with real shared IPs, there is no chance to show the server outside the LAN".